# this.functionName is not a function error

Tags: javascript, oop

I am writing a simulation for bunny survival in a meadow and have to detect the minimal plant growth rate for the bunny to survive. I decided to go with OOP. Hence, tried to design my "classes" in js. I haven't done much OOP in JS, so I am stuck. I don't understand why I keep getting "this.checkElementExists" is not a function.

I tried to follow OOP that was shown in Mozilla MDN for JS and here I am stuck. I updated to ES6 classes.

```
class Meadow{

    constructor(){
        this.grid = this.makeGrid();
        //console.log(this.grid);
    }

    makeGrid(){
        let grid = new Array(30);
        for(var i=0; i < 30; i++){
            grid[i] = new Array(30).fill(null);
        }

        return grid;
    }

    checkElementExists(coordinates){
        if(this.grid[coordinates[0]][coordinates[1]] != null){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    growAPlant(timeRate){
        if(timeRate == null){
            clearInterval(this.growAPlant);
        }
        let plant = new Plant();
        let coord = plant.generateCoordinateInMeadow();
        //console.log(coord);
        // add a plant to the 2d array, but check if the that spot is free
        // otherwise use the generateCOordinate in the meadow function
        //console.log(this.grid[coord[0]][coord[1]]);
        //var that = this;
        var ans = checkElementExists(coord).bind(this);
        console.log(ans);
        while(!checkElementExists(coord)){
            coord = plant.generateCoordinateInMeadow();
        }
        //console.log(coord);
        //console.log(this.grid[coord[0]] == undefined);
        this.grid[coord[0]][coord[1]] = plant;
        //console.log(this.grid);
    }
}

class Simulation{

constructor(){
    this.passRateArray = []; // this array will be used to plot the data
    this.failureRateArray = []; // array that will hold failure growth rates
    this.timeToEnergyData = []; // an example would be [{0: 1000, 1: 999, 2: 998, ....., 10000: 0}]
    this.rateToEnergyTimeData = {};
    this.timeCounter = 100; // 10000
    this.growthTimeRate = 1000; // 1 second
    this.gap = 0.05;
    this.meadow = new Meadow();
    this.bunny = new Bunny();
}


timeToEnergyDataPopulator(currTime, energy){
    var relation = {currTime : energy};
    this.timeToEnergyData.push(relation);
}

simulation(){
    // HERE I MAKE A CALL TO MEADOW.GROWAPLANT
    setInterval(this.meadow.growAPlant.bind(this.meadow), this.growthTimeRate);
    //meadow.growAPlant(this.growthTimeRate);
    let bunnyMove = this.bunny.move();  

    // not enough energy, bunny did not survive
    if(bunnyMove == false){
        this.timeToEnergyDataPopulator(this.timeCounter, bunny.getBunnyEnergy());

        let rate = this.growthTimeRate / 1000;
        this.rateToEnergyTimeData = {rate : this.timeToEnergyData};
        // add the failure rate to the failureRateArray
        this.failureRateArray.push(this.growthTimeRate);
        //  increase the rate of plant growth
        if(this.passRateArray.length < 1){
            this.growthTimeRate = this.growthTimeRate + this.growthTimeRate * 0.5;
        }else{
            let lastSurvivalRate = this.passRateArray[this.passRateArray.length - 1];
            this.growthTimeRate = lastSurvivalRate - ((lastSurvivalRate - this.growthTimeRate)*0.5);
        }

        // stop the meadow from growing a plant
        meadow.growAPlant(null);
        // stop the simulation
        clearInterval(this.simulation);
    }
    while(!this.meadow.checkValidBunnyMove(bunnyMove).bind(this.meadow)){
        bunnyMove = bunny.move();
    }
    if(meadow.checkIfBunnyEats(bunnyMove)){
        // since bunny made still a move, -1 energy
        bunny.decreaseEnergyByOne();
        // and since the meadow at that coordinate had food, we add +10 to energy via eatPlant method
        bunny.eatPlant();
        // track the time to energy data
        this.timeToEnergyDataPopulator(this.timeCounter, bunny.getBunnyEnergy);
    }else{
        // no food, -1 energy
        bunny.decreaseEnergyByOne();
        // track the time to energy data
        this.timeToEnergyDataPopulator(this.timeCounter, bunny.getBunnyEnergy);
    }
    // decrement the timeCounter
    this.timeCounter -= 1;
    if(this.timeCounter <= 0){
        this.timeToEnergyDataPopulator(this.timeCounter, bunny.getBunnyEnergy());

        let rate = this.growthTimeRate / 1000;
        this.rateToEnergyTimeData = {rate : this.timeToEnergyData};

        this.passRateArray.push(this.growthTimeRate);

        // bunny survived, adjust the growth rate
        if(this.failureRateArray.length < 1){
            this.growthTimeRate = this.growthTimeRate - (this.growthTimeRate * 0.5);
        }else{
            let lastFailureRate = this.failureRateArray[this.failureRateArray.length - 1];
            this.growthTimeRate = this.growthTimeRate - ((this.growthTimeRate - lastFailureRate) * 0.5);
        }
        clearInterval(this.simulation);
    }
}

runner(){
    while(this.passRateArray[this.passRateArray.length - 1] - this.failureRateArray[this.failureRateArray.length - 1] > this.gap || this.passRateArray.length == 0 || this.failureRateArray.length == 0){
        setInterval(this.simulation(), 1000);  
    }
    console.log("The minimum plant regeneration rate required to sustain the bunny for 10000 units of time is " + 
        this.growthTimeRate + " regenerations/unit time");
}
```

}

Errors that I get:
1) simulation.js:62 Uncaught TypeError: this.meadow.checkValidBunnyMove is not a function
    at Simulation.simulation (simulation.js:62)
    at Simulation.runner (simulation.js:101)
    at (index):24
2) meadow.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Meadow' has already been declared
    at VM16689 meadow.js:1
3) VM16689 meadow.js:37 Uncaught ReferenceError: checkElementExists is not defined
    at Meadow.growAPlant (VM16689 meadow.js:37)

My question is why the number 1 and 3 errors persist?

Comment: I would recommend updating your code to an [ES6 class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), what you have is the old way of making classes.

Comment: I will try the ES6 way of OOP and see if the issue persists.

Comment: The problem still persists...

Comment: I made a minimalistic class, and it works for me.

Comment: Can you rely on ES6 support? If so, please update the question to that attempt for simplicity. Anyway, `clearInterval(this.growAPlant)` isn’t correct and the problem is with the corresponding `setInterval`.

Comment: @Ry- Just FYI, if you comment out the `clearInterval`, the error still persists.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: There’s no `setInterval`.

Comment: @Ry- sorry I meant `clearInterval`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: Because “the problem is with the corresponding `setInterval`”.

Comment: @Ry- Would it be possible if I post my other class where I call setInterval and still get some errors that I have no clue of why they appear to be there.

Comment: You don’t have a function called `checkValidBunnyMove` here. Adding `.bind(…)` to the end of that doesn’t make sense either. `setInterval(this.simulation(), 1000)` is incorrect. Get things working individually before trying to change everything at once.

Answer (score 0):

```
clearInterval(this.growAPlant);
```

This `clearInterval` isn’t correct, because you need pass the return value of `setInterval` to it, not a function. It does helpfully imply that you have a `setInterval(someMeadow.growAPlant, …)` somewhere, though, and that’s where the issue is. When you reference a function without calling it – like when you pass it to `setInterval` – the object it belonged to doesn’t come with it. Then, when the timer fires, it calls the function without a `this` value.

In JavaScript, the value of `this` inside a non-[arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function is determined entirely by how the function is called, not where it’s declared. You can read about how `this` works in various other questions and pieces of documentation. Fixing the problem involves giving `growAPlant` the correct `this` somehow, either by:

1. placing a reference to it in a containing scope (i.e. moving your `var that = this` out one level and using `that` instead of `this` throughout)
2. wrapping the function in one that’ll preserve the correct value, as in

   ```
   setInterval(someMeadow.growAPlant.bind(someMeadow), …);
   ```

   ([`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)) or

   ```
   setInterval(function () {
       someMeadow.growAPlant();
   }, …);
   ```

   (the `someMeadow.growAPlant` reference is now part of a call, so `someMeadow` becomes the `this` value for the call)
3. changing it into an arrow function, which doesn’t have its own `this` and uses the one from the containing scope

Only (2) will work when you convert to the simplest form of an ES6 class, so it’s the approach I recommend.

Answer (score -1):

### Explanation

First, `this` always refers to the first parent `function`. In your case it is:

```
this.growAPlant = function(timeRate){
    //content
    var that = this; // this is growAPlant
}
```

**And**

```
this.checkElementExists = function(coordinates){ }
```

Is accessible with `Meadow` object. However, your `var that` is referring to `this.growAPlant = function(timeRate)` not `Meadow`.

### Solution

Create `that` in the beginning

```
function Meadow(){
   var that = this;

   that.growAPlant = function(timeRate){
   }
   
   that.checkElementExists = function(coordinates){
       if(this.grid[coordinates[0]][coordinates[1]] != null){
          return true;
       }else{
          return false;
       }
   }; 

   return that;
}
```

Comment: The first part is incorrect. `this` rarely refers to a function.